# How to isolate the first value in a consecutive subsequence in a pandas series/column?

Tags: python, pandas

How would I convert a series of the form:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([True,True, True, False, False, False, True, True, False], columns=['signal'])
df
   signal
0    True
1    True
2    True
3   False
4   False
5   False
6    True
7    True
8   False
```

to a series where the first value which meets a certain criteria, is preserved and the consecutive ones are not? like the following:

```
   signal
0    True
1   False
2   False
3   False
4   False
5   False
6    True
7   False
8   False
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['signal'] & ~(df['signal'].shift(1).fillna(False))
   signal
0    True
1   False
2   False
3   False
4   False
5   False
6    True
7   False
8   False
```

This takes the original series and does a logical AND with a series that is shifted forward by 1 and inverted.

We want to keep the first value in the consecutive series, so when we shift forward by 1, the first `True` value in the original series will have a corresponding `False` value in the shifted series. We want to resolve to `True` in the result when the original series is `True` and the shifted series is `False`, and not the other way around, so we cannot do a simple XOR.

We need to invert the shifted series, so the original series and the shifted/inverted series will both be `True` so a logical AND will resolve to `True`.

The `fillna(False)` is needed since we will have `NaN` when shifting